# getting count from the same column in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wanted to a count of the same field for different values for example:

> user{user_id, gender}

Gender can have obviously male or female :)

i want to get count for all the males and females i.e.

```
COUNT(male)   COUNT(female)  
   4               16
```

but im confused because they come from the same `gender coloumn` thanks

Comment: do you want the results in the same column (two rows) or two columns (one row)?

Comment: good question, i want them in 3 rows including the total users, number of males and number of females

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this for row wise result:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(User_id) AS count
FROM User
GROUP BY gender;
```

Output:

```
| gender | count |
|--------|-------|
|      F |     4 |
|      M |     2 |
```

Try this for row wise result with grand total:

```
SELECT  (IFNull(gender,'Total')) AS gender,
COUNT(User_id) AS Count
FROM User
GROUP BY gender
WITH rollup;
```

Output:

```
| gender | Count |
|--------|-------|
|      F |     4 |
|      M |     2 |
|  Total |     6 |
```

Try this for column wise result:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN User_id END) AS males,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN User_id END) AS females,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM User;
```

Output:

```
| males | females | Total |
|-------|---------|-------|
|     2 |       4 |     6 |
```

##### [*See this SQL Fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52507bf72e7dc434ef090aa4039b31ac)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, you want count for both males, females and the total count:

```
SELECT sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) males,
  sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) females,
  count(*) total
FROM  yourTable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e4b4/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  COUNT(IF(gender = 'M', User_id, NULL)) males,
  COUNT(IF(gender = 'F', User_id, NULL)) females
FROM
  User
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
with total count:

```
Select gender,count(*) as count
From User
Group by gender
with rollup
```

[SQl Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0c88/1)