# Calculate total males and females in each group with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by, aggregate-functions

How can I find the number of males and females in each section using CodeIgniter's query builder methods?

I've already tried `Count`, `select`, `sum` with grouping, but I still cannot achieve my desired result.

What I want is to get the section name, its total students, and its separate male and female counts. I want do this with 1 query.

Desired output:

| Male | Female |
| --- | --- |
| Section 1 | 10 |
| Section 2 | 8 |

Table Schema:

- tbl_section: section_id, section_name
- tbl_student: stud_id,stud_name,gender,section_id(foreign key)

My coding attempt:

```
$total =$this->db
    ->selectCount('gender')
    ->from(tbl_student)
    ->join('tbl_section','tbl_student.section_id = tbl_section.section_id)
    ->where('tbl_student.gender = "male")
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

Raw SQL attempt:

```
select section.section_name,count(stud_id)
from tbl_student
join section on tbl_student.section_id=section.section_id
where tbl_student.gender = "Male"
group by section.section_id;
```

Outcome: Only 1 gender displayed -- I want to display both male and female.

Comment: what is your table schema?

Comment: i've added my table scheme

Comment: show us your code and we can correct it.  `Count Select Sum with Group` means nothing. Especially since `SELECT` is always first

Comment: i've added the code sir.. i can count the male but i i dont know to count the female in 1 query only and display what section are they. for excel report

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you know how to perform this task with pure SQL?  This is always the first step.  Translating to CodeIgniter's query builder methods is a nice-to-have.  Surely this page will inspire (spoonfeed) you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11986617/2943403

Comment: @Jomar Firstly, you had to remove `where tbl_student.gender = ...` clause.
Secondly, replace COUNT by SUM (if I correctly, 10, 5, 8, ... is number of students for a gender).
For the last, you should show full table stucture, and explain more about meaning of columns

Comment: the count is right but the problem is that it only display the section name and the count of male. i want both male and female

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by the section ids, then calculate two conditional counts in the select that relate to each grouped section id.

The raw SQL looks like this:  ([db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/djfpmm343SLu1AaKsceaZs/1))

```
SELECT sec.section_name, SUM(gender = 'M') males, SUM(gender = 'F') females
FROM tbl_section AS sec
JOIN tbl_student AS stu ON sec.section_id = stu.section_id
GROUP BY section_name
```

To translate this to CI's query builder methods:

```
return $this->db
    ->select("sec.section_name section, SUM(gender = 'M') males, SUM(gender = 'F') females")
    ->from('tbl_section sec')
    ->join('tbl_student stu', 'sec.section_id = stu.section_id')
    ->group_by('section_name')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```